# (SDL Render Problem) C++ Exception Thrown: read access violation. THIS was nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, null, sdl

Whenever I run my program I get an exception thrown on two seperate lines of code should I comment one of them out the problem jumps to another but both refer to the same variable.

GameScreenManager.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Commons.h"
#include "GameScreenManager.h"
#include "GameScreenLevel1.h"
#include "GameScreen.h"

GameScreenManager::GameScreenManager(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SCREENS startScreen)
{
    SDL_Renderer* mRenderer;
    mRenderer = NULL;
    ChangeScreen(startScreen);
}

GameScreenManager::~GameScreenManager()
{
    mRenderer = NULL;
    delete mCurrentScreen;
    mCurrentScreen = NULL;
}

void GameScreenManager::Render()
{
    mCurrentScreen->Render();
}

void GameScreenManager::update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e)
{
    mCurrentScreen->Update(deltaTime, e);
}

void GameScreenManager::ChangeScreen(SCREENS newScreen)
{
    //Clear up the old screen
    if (mCurrentScreen != NULL)
    {
        delete mCurrentScreen;
    }

    GameScreenLevel1* tempScreen;


    switch (newScreen)
    {
    case SCREEN_INTRO:
        break;
    case SCREEN_MENU:
        break;
    case SCREEN_LEVEL1:
        tempScreen = new GameScreenLevel1(mRenderer);
        mCurrentScreen = (GameScreen*)tempScreen;
        tempScreen = NULL;
        break;
    case SCREEN_LEVEL2:
        break;
    case SCREEN_GAMEOVER:
        break;
    case SCREEN_HIGHSCORES:
        break;
    default:
            break;
    }
}
```

GameScreenManager.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _GAMESCREENMANAGER_H
#define _GAMESCREENMANAGER_H
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Commons.h"

class GameScreen;

class GameScreenManager
{
    private:
        SDL_Renderer*    mRenderer;
        GameScreen*      mCurrentScreen;

    public:
        GameScreenManager(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SCREENS startScreen);
        ~GameScreenManager();

        void Render();
        void update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e);
        void ChangeScreen(SCREENS newScreen);
};

#endif //_GAMESCREENMANAGER_H
```

Currently the problem occurs on line 24;

```
    mCurrentScreen->Render();
```

However if I comment out that line then it appears on line 29:

```
    mCurrentScreen->Update(deltaTime, e);
```

"Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
**this** was nullptr. occurred"

Comment: A program often crashes miles away from where the bug actually was. The error message *`this` was nullptr* suggests you should find out why `this` was `nullptr`. Was `mCurrentScreen = (GameScreen*)tempScreen;` missed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the mCurrentScreen field is NULL when you call Render() or update(). Either protect calls by checking the mCurrentScreen for NULL:

```
void GameScreenManager::Render()
{
    if (mCurrentScreen != NULL)
        mCurrentScreen->Render();
}

void GameScreenManager::update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e)
{
    if (mCurrentScreen != NULL)
        mCurrentScreen->Update(deltaTime, e);
}
```

or make sure that mCurrentScreen is set before calling Render() or Update().

Comment: I added the if statements to check if the mCurrentScreen != NULL and proceed accordingly however I still get the exception thrown, however this time on the if statements.

Comment: set mCurrentScreen to NULL after you delete it in ChangeScreen()

Comment: If `mCurrentScreen` is not guaranteed to be pointed at something safe  before it is used, you are doomed to surrounding every use with an `if (mCurrentScreen != NULL)`. This is playing bug whack-a-mole because you'll be constantly finding cases where it was not set. and not tested. You're much better off making sure that `mCurrentScreen` *always* points to something safe.

Comment: I set mCurrentScreen to NULL after the delete mCurrentScreen and still get the exception. I even removed that if statement entirely and still no luck.

Comment: If the exception is thrown on if statement, than something is wrong with your build probably - try clean / rebuild, delete all intermediate files etc. You should also initialize mCurrentScreen to NULL in the constructor, but it wouldn't help you with throwing exceptions on "if"s.

Comment: Aren't you calling Render or Update *after* deallocating your GameScreenManager? Place a breakpoint to the destructor, to be sure...

Comment: Ive added "mCurrentScreen = NULL;" to the constructor but still no luck. Im following along to a tutorial series provided for by my University and some of the parts are down right confusing, doesnt help that they're all in Word documents with no videos or screenshots of what the code should look like.

Comment: It's also possible that you never instantiate the GameScreenManager, or you do, but do not use the right pointer. Add breakpoint to the constructor, and check if 'this' has the same value as in Render or Update...

Answer (score 0):

As it happens I had actually missed a line of code that set the mCurrentScreen and the switch statement was not passing through correctly so it was not firing. In addition the mRenderer variable was not setup correctly in any of my cpp files, as such returned "Invalid Renderer" whenever I tried to use it. The following is the working code, thanks for the help everyone it steered me in the right direction;

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Commons.h"
#include "GameScreenManager.h"
#include "GameScreenLevel1.h"
#include "GameScreen.h"

GameScreenManager::GameScreenManager(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SCREENS startScreen)
{
    mRenderer = renderer;
    GameScreen* mCurrentScreen = NULL;
    ChangeScreen(startScreen);
}

GameScreenManager::~GameScreenManager()
{
    mRenderer = NULL;
    delete mCurrentScreen;
    mCurrentScreen = NULL;
}

void GameScreenManager::Render()
{
    mCurrentScreen->Render();
}

void GameScreenManager::Update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e)
{
    mCurrentScreen->Update(deltaTime, e);
}

void GameScreenManager::ChangeScreen(SCREENS newScreen)
{
    //Clear up the old screen
    if (mCurrentScreen != NULL)
    {
        delete mCurrentScreen;
    }

    GameScreenLevel1* tempScreen;

    switch (newScreen)
    {
    case SCREEN_INTRO:
        break;
    case SCREEN_MENU:
        break;
    case SCREEN_LEVEL1:
        tempScreen = new GameScreenLevel1(mRenderer);
        mCurrentScreen = (GameScreen*)tempScreen;
        tempScreen = NULL;
        break;
    case SCREEN_LEVEL2:
        break;
    case SCREEN_GAMEOVER:
        break;
    case SCREEN_HIGHSCORES:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```